# Jenkins git plugin: Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins

I am having trouble using the jenkins git plugin while trying to connect to a repo hosted via https.

```
Baue in Arbeitsbereich /opt/jenkins/jobs/TestJob2/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://my.host.de/group/project # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://my.host.de/group/project
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Jenkins at my.host.de
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://my.host.de/group/project +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://my.host.de/group/project
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:766)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1022)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1053)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://my.host.de/group/project +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://my.host.de/group/project/': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1709)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1438)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:764)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

I can't use SSH.
The certificate is okay, and everything looks great.

`curl -Lv` does not show any errors.

I can clone the repository locally ont hat machine when logging in via ssh, no error message either.

Where is the switch I have to change?

I can change this behaviour when setting the git property `http.sslVerify` to false for the user jenkins is running on, but this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just spent an hour investigating on such an issue.

After setting up CA I tested that on master everything worked great with custom CA being configured into the system.

It took me unfortunately some time to realize that **ALL** Jenkins agents need to have proper gitconfig or CA certificates installed for it to work properly.

Comment: I can't remember what helped in my case but your answer looks legit ;)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem adding to `.gitconfig` file the **sslCAInfo** info, like this:

```
$ echo -e "[http]\n\tsslCAInfo = /FOLDER_OF_CERTIFICATE/ca.pem" >> /var/lib/jenkins/.gitconfig
```

I was working with openshift... and I did it to master and the slaves to

Comment: This solution has solved my problem using Jenkins inside OpenShift 4.5... literally we can do exactly that. Create a file `.gitconfig` with the correct content. and put it together with the certificate in the path: `/var/lib/jenkins`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would also be a good idea to check your proxy server settings along with other git/openssl options. It helped me resolve this issue just by updating the correct proxy settings.